# ASP.NET Web App hosted in IIS using Azure Active Directory Sign in Page by default

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application that is deployed in an Azure VM. I have configured the IIS Server and everything but there is no Authentication in place. Anyone can access to the Web Application.

I want to configure my Web Application so every time anyone who tries to go to my Web Application it redirects before to the Microsoft Azure Active Directory login. If the user name and password is part of the Azure Active Directory, I want them to go into the web app, otherwise it should fail.

I've seen lots of tutorials when you deploy an Azure App Service and looks super easy, however, how does it get done when you deploy your web application in an Azure Virtual Machine?

**EDIT**: I found a tutorial that does exactly what I need and it works fine

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

However, how can I redirect to ALWAYS ask for sign in before the Web App loads?

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that when an authentication request is sent, the user is always forced to enter credentials no matter what session cookies might already be in place ,  OpenID Connect will behave that way upon receiving a `prompt=login` parameter in the request :

```
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        //
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        //
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                    }
```

Even if you have login into azure ad before , with that parameter , user will be asked to enter credentials .